# map over json object and set first object.value as state

Tags: reactjs

I currently have my code like this:

```
    renderDiagnosisCodeValue(){
    return _.map(this.state.diagnosisData && this.state.diagnosisData, diagnosisValues => {
      this.setState({
        diagnosisReturnedValue: diagnosisValues[0].diagnosisCode
      })
      return(
        <option key={diagnosisValues.id} value={diagnosisValues.diagnosisCode}>{diagnosisValues.diagnosisName}</option>
      )
    });
  }
```

But its returning me this `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'diagnosisCode' of undefined`

The reason why I want to do this its because I want to set my initial state to the first object.value. This `<option>` are inside a `<select>` hearing to an onChange event, but if the user decides to select the first option without triggering the onChange handler the value will be empty, so thats why I need to set it up as initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call setState in the render method. What you should be doing instead is setting the initial state after you fetch the data. So you should move `this.setState` into `componentDidMount` or wherever you are fetching the initial data.

Or a real dirty approach would be:

```
this.setState({
    diagnosisReturnedValue: this.state.diagnosisData[0].diagnosisValues[0].diagnosisCode
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I setState where i was fetching the initial data. Thank you very much for the quick response